# Fill a List with zeros in Java

Tags: java, list, fill, zero

I'm working in Java and I have a list of objects of type TimestampAndValue:

```
public class TimestampAndValue{
    private double value;
    private long timestamp;

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

My list is similar to this:

- Element 1: timestamp = 0, value = 5
- Element 2: timestamp = 4, value = 6
- Element 3: timestamp = 6, value = 10
- Element 4: timestamp = 12, value = 1

And I want to have this list in output:

- Element 1: timestamp = 0, value = 5
- Element 2: timestamp = 1, value = 0
- Element 3: timestamp = 3, value = 0
- Element 4: timestamp = 4, value = 6
- Element 5: timestamp = 5, value = 0
- Element 6: timestamp = 6, value = 10
- Element 7: timestamp = 7, value = 0
- Element 8: timestamp = 11, value = 0
- Element 9: timestamp = 12, value = 1

I'll try to explain what I need in short. When two timestamps aren't contiguous integers, I need to place the minimum number of zeros between them. For example in the case between the timestamp 4 and 6 in the above list I need to place only one zero, but in the case in which two timestamps differ by two or more I need to place a zero right after the first timestamp and a zero immediately before the second timestamp. You can see this in the case between timestamp 6 and 10. I need also that the placed zeros have the correct timestamp set.

For now I can't figure out how to solve it. Thank you for your support!

This is the solution which worked for me using your suggestions:

```
public static List<TimestampAndValue> insertMinimumNumberOfZerosBetweenValues(List<TimestampAndValue> list){
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty() || list.size() == 1)
        return list;

    int i;
    int j;
    long tempTimestamp1;
    long tempTimestamp2;
    long timestampDifference;

    List<TimestampAndValue> outList = new ArrayList<TimestampAndValue>();

    outList.add(list.get(0));
    for(i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
        j=i+1;

        tempTimestamp1 = list.get(i).getTimestamp();
        tempTimestamp2 = list.get(j).getTimestamp();
        timestampDifference = tempTimestamp2 - tempTimestamp1;

        if(timestampDifference == 2){
            TimestampAndValue tav = new TimestampAndValue();
            tav.setTimestamp(tempTimestamp1 + 1);
            tav.setValue(0);

            outList.add(tav);
        }
        else if(timestampDifference > 2){
            TimestampAndValue tav = new TimestampAndValue();
            tav.setTimestamp(tempTimestamp1 + 1);
            tav.setValue(0);

            outList.add(tav);

            TimestampAndValue tav2 = new TimestampAndValue();
            tav2.setTimestamp(tempTimestamp2 - 1);
            tav2.setValue(0);

            outList.add(tav2);
        }                

        outList.add(list.get(j));
    }

    return outList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to process pairs of timestamps from the input list, accumulating an output list:

```
outputList = new list of timestamps;

for (int i = 0; i < numerOfTimestamps-1; i++) {
    timestamp1 = inputList.get(i);
    timestamp2 = inputList.get(i+1);
```

For each pair compare the distance between them:

- if they are contiguos, add `timestamp1` to output list
- if the difference is less than two, add `timestamp1` and a new timestamp with `0` to output list
- if the difference is equal to or greater than two, add `timestamp1` and two new timestamps with `0` to output list

Then

```
} // close loop
```

and add the last timestamp to the output list. (It's never added by the loop.)

Note that you need to treat the empty input list separately.

Comment: Thank you! I've used your suggestion to write the method I need! I've also posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  I'm not solving your problem correctly, but have you tried to implement a mechanism in wich returns a default value of 0 if the timestamp doesn't exist? It will be much more efficient and simple

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?  If so, please tag as such.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but I would think a simple loop should work.  Sort your list by timestamp, then loop over all the values.  As soon as you find a non-contiguous timestamp, insert a 0 entry.

Answer (score 0):

First a question *Why* would you need those integers in between?

Next a suggestion (not tested):

```
List<TimestampAndValue> newList = new ArrayList<TimestampAndValue>();
TimestampAndValue lastAdded = null;    

for( int i = 0; i < oldList.length; i++ ) {   
  if( i > 0 && !isContiguous(lastAdded, oldList[i])) {
    newList.add(new TimestampAndValue(oldList[i].timestamp - 1, 0.0 ) );
  }

  newList.add( oldList[i] );
  lastAdded = oldList[i];

  if( i < (oldList.length - 1) && !isContiguous(oldList[i], oldList[i+1]) {
    lastAdded = new TimestampAndValue(oldList[i].timestamp + 1, 0.0 );
    newList.add( lastAdded );
  }
}
```

Basically you iterate over the list and insert the elements into a new list. If the last value in the new list is not contiguous, add a 0 entry first. If the next entry won't be contiguous, add a 0 entry afterwards.

Note that you still need to implement `isContiguous( ... )` and handle null correctly.